# Pegar a altura de uma imagem

Tags: jquery, css, css3

No meu projeto, eu tenho uma imagem que à medida em que vai se reduzindo o ecrã *1000px, 860px, 320px, etc* a imagem também vai alterando sua altura.

Como fazer para pegar a altura no momento da exibição?

Preciso saber essa altura para setar o `margin-top` de uma `div` que vai abaixo dela.

Answer (score 1):

Duas alternativas, usando `.getBoundingClientRect` e `getComputedStyle`.

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var altura = img.getBoundingClientRect().height;
var altura2 = window.getComputedStyle(img).height;
console.log(altura, altura2);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7u41sg3/

Na prática o ideal é teres o elemento em cache com `var img = document...` e depois quando precisares de saber as dimensões usar uma das opções em cima. Se explicares melhor como mudas o tamanho das imagens que tens posso dar um exemplo mais completo/adaptado.

Comment: com JQuery  alguma saida?

Comment: @CarlosRocha ... quanto menos jQuery melhor. Sim, há uma maneira com jQuery: `var altura = $('img').height();`

Comment: Esse é o problema. A altura esta dando muito alta quando dimiuo a resolução. Embora a imagem apareça corretamente a informação da altura dá errada, Veja http://hotplateprensas.com.br/novo/

Comment: no localhost, está retornando 88 com o browser aberto no máximo. Na web dá 0px; Quando diminuo a resolução para 350px então local dá 9723px e na web dá 0 também.

Comment: como implementar var img = document.querySelector('img'); com o id da imagem?

Comment: tentei assim alert($("#logo").innerHeight());, deu a mesma coisa

Comment: fiz assim   alturaLogo = $("#logo").innerHeight();
  alert(alturaLogo);
  $(".topo").css("height",alturaLogo+" !important"); Na inspetor diz que a altura é 110.531, já no JQuery diz que é 147

Comment: @CarlosRocha o jQuery usa o `getBoundingClientRect`. Para mim mostra o mesmo no inpetor e na consola. Que browser estás a usar?

Comment: estou usando google chome

Comment: @CarlosRocha podes fazer um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema?

Comment: Posso te enviar o link de onde está o problema: http://hotplateprensas.com.br/novo/. Pos é muita coisa para colocar lá e saber filtrar o que por é que são elas